# Issue with if statement on my JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an if statement for this code to only allow records with experience level 1-3 to show but not sure how to do it? this is partial code if need more let me know.

```
var table = document.getElementById('blueteam');

        table.innerHTML = ""; //Clears table
    if(explevel < 4){
        for (var i = 0; i < firstnames.length; i += 1) {
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            var cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.innerHTML = firstnames[i] + " " + lastnames[i] + " Exp:" + explevel[i];
        }
    }
    };
```

Comment: What is explevel? Where is it defined?

Comment: I think you need to display more of the source code "Relevant source" I have no idea where `explevel`  is being defined or `firstnames`.

Comment: try `if(+explevel[i] < 4){` the if should also be in the `for` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
var table = document.getElementById('blueteam');

    table.innerHTML = ""; //Clears table

    for (var i = 0; i < firstnames.length; i += 1) {
        if(explevel[i] >= 1 && explevel[i] <= 3){
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            var cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.innerHTML = firstnames[i] + " " + lastnames[i] + " Exp:" + explevel[i];
        }
    }
};
```

You were calling if `explevel < 4` but since `explevel` is a list (`explevel[i]`), you cannot do that. Instead, check each iteration of `explevel`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var table = document.getElementById('blueteam');

    table.innerHTML = ""; //Clears table
    var count = records.length;
    var record;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        record = records[i];
        if (reecord.explevel < 4) {
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            var cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.innerHTML = record.firstname + " " + record.lastname + " Exp:" + record.explevel;   
        }
    }
```

I modified the data. I am not sure of `firstnames`, `lastnames` and `explevel`. I hope those should be present inside the `record`.

**Sample Data**

```
var records = [{
    "firstname": "",
    "lastname": "",
    "explevel": ""
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the logical `AND (&&)` operator: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

```
var table = document.getElementById('blueteam');

table.innerHTML = ""; //Clears table
for (var i = 0; i < firstnames.length; i++) {    
    if((explevel[i] >= 1) && (explevel[i] <= 3)){
        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = firstnames[i] + " " + lastnames[i] + " Exp:" + explevel[i];
    }
}
```